# Merging multiple rows with the same index into one row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some really dirty repeating data in a spreadsheet I need to clean up and extract some values. Basically I have records stored in rows, with one record per column. Once I hit the column limit (let's say 5 in my example below), the records 'carriage return' into another set of rows.

Here's an example of the output of the dataframe:

| Index | Unnamed 1 | Unnamed 2 | Unnamed 3 | Unnamed 4 | Unnamed 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fruit | Banana | Orange | Apple | Grape | Tomato |
| Colour | Yellow | Orange | Green | Green | Red |
| Quantity | 5 | 7 | 2 | 20 | 2 |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Fruit | Pear | Watermelon | NaN | NaN | Nan |
| Colour | Green | Green | NaN | NaN | Nan |
| Quantity | 4 | 7 | NaN | NaN | Nan |

So you can see I have repeating indexes.

Ultimately I want to push out a CSV with this data tidied up:

| Fruit | Colour | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Banana | Yellow | 5 |
| Orange | Orange | 7 |
| Apple | Green | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Watermelon | Green | 7 |

I know how I can reference the rows using iLoc, but I need to repeat this process for many source files, where the exact row numbers change (there is unrelated data above and below this data set).

How can I concatenate all the fruit rows, colour rows, quantity rows into a set of columns that I can then transpose? I've tried merge, join, group by, all the usual suspects, but not quite getting it!

Answer (score 0):

Considering you initial dataframe **df**, you should remove all rows with NANs (1st line of code), and make 'Index' column you index (2nd line of code).

```
df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
df = df.set_index('Index')
```

Since the dataframe repeats every 3 lines, you should split the dataframe into a list of dataframes with this step. The transpose (.T) makes the Index - Fruit, Colour and Quantity into columns.

```
n=3
list_df = [df[i:i+n].T for i in range(0,df.shape[0],n)]
```

Finally, do the concatenate the list back to a dataframe,

```
final_df = pd.concat(list_df, ignore_index=True, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()

l = []
for n, g in df.groupby(df['Index'].isna().cumsum()):
    l.append(g.dropna(how='all', axis=0).set_index('Index').T)
    
df_out = pd.concat(l, ignore_index=True).dropna(how='all')
df_out
```

Output:

```
Index       Fruit  Colour Quantity
0          Banana  Yellow        5
1          Orange  Orange        7
2           Apple   Green        2
3           Grape   Green       20
4          Tomato     Red        2
5            Pear   Green        4
6      Watermelon   Green        7
9             Nan     Nan      Nan
```

*Note:*  Last row is do 'NaN' vs 'Nan' in input dataframe above.